# Navbar hide on scroll down, show on scroll up doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my navbar. I want it to disappear when the user scrolls down, and when the user scrolls up I want it do appear again.

However my problem is that it works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc but in Safari I have a problem. When I scroll to the top of the page (only in Safari) the "hide navbar" function triggers as if the user scrolls down. Doest it have to do with that the window returns 0?

Do any one of you know what seems to be the problem or can point me in the right direction, I would be most grateful!

Please just ask if you need any more information and I will try to explain it further.

Here is my code (OPEN in Safari to see the issue):

https://jsfiddle.net/erikwaahlstrom/wyagt61z/25/

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (currentScrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
    $('.main-nav').addClass('hidden');
  } else {
    $('.main-nav').removeClass('hidden');
  }

  lastScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #888888;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
}

.hidden {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.main-nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  z-index: 801;
}

#menu_toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  left: 400px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 45px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 801;
}

#menu_toggle span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

#menu_toggle span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 17px;
}

#menu_toggle span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 17px;
}

#menu_toggle span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 17px;
}

#menu_toggle span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: 12px;
}

#menu_toggle.open span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#menu_toggle.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 20.5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#menu_toggle.open span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 20.5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#menu_toggle.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Navigation bar -->
<div class="container-fluid main-nav">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-10 mx-auto">

        <a class="logotype" href="home">

          <h1>Logo</h1>

        </a>

        <div id="menu_toggle">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<p>Det finns många olika varianter av Lorem Ipsum, men majoriteten av dessa har ändrats på någotvis. Antingen med inslag av humor, eller med inlägg av ord som knappast ser trovärdiga ut. Skall man använda långa stycken av Lorem Ipsum bör man försäkra sig
  om att det inte gömmer sig något pinsamt mitt i texten. Lorem Ipsum-generatorer på internet tenderar att repetera Lorem Ipsum-texten styckvis efter behov, något som gör denna sidan till den första riktiga Lorem Ipsum-generatorn på internet. Den använder
  ett ordförråd på över 200 ord, kombinerat med ett antal meningsbyggnadsstrukturer som tillsamman genererar Lorem Ipsum som ser ut som en normal mening. Lorem Ipsum genererad på denna sidan är därför alltid fri från repetitioner, humorinslag, märkliga
  ordformationer osv.</p>

<p>Det finns många olika varianter av Lorem Ipsum, men majoriteten av dessa har ändrats på någotvis. Antingen med inslag av humor, eller med inlägg av ord som knappast ser trovärdiga ut. Skall man använda långa stycken av Lorem Ipsum bör man försäkra sig
  om att det inte gömmer sig något pinsamt mitt i texten. Lorem Ipsum-generatorer på internet tenderar att repetera Lorem Ipsum-texten styckvis efter behov, något som gör denna sidan till den första riktiga Lorem Ipsum-generatorn på internet. Den använder
  ett ordförråd på över 200 ord, kombinerat med ett antal meningsbyggnadsstrukturer som tillsamman genererar Lorem Ipsum som ser ut som en normal mening. Lorem Ipsum genererad på denna sidan är därför alltid fri från repetitioner, humorinslag, märkliga
  ordformationer osv.</p>
<p>Det finns många olika varianter av Lorem Ipsum, men majoriteten av dessa har ändrats på någotvis. Antingen med inslag av humor, eller med inlägg av ord som knappast ser trovärdiga ut. Skall man använda långa stycken av Lorem Ipsum bör man försäkra sig
  om att det inte gömmer sig något pinsamt mitt i texten. Lorem Ipsum-generatorer på internet tenderar att repetera Lorem Ipsum-texten styckvis efter behov, något som gör denna sidan till den första riktiga Lorem Ipsum-generatorn på internet. Den använder
  ett ordförråd på över 200 ord, kombinerat med ett antal meningsbyggnadsstrukturer som tillsamman genererar Lorem Ipsum som ser ut som en normal mening. Lorem Ipsum genererad på denna sidan är därför alltid fri från repetitioner, humorinslag, märkliga
  ordformationer osv.</p>
```

Comment: have you tried using `-webkit-`  prefix on the transform style ?

Comment: Hmm interesting, I've tried it now but haven't got it to work yet @Takit Isy